# How to checkout file using PowerShell REST API in SharePoint Server 2013 located in subsite?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell, document-library, check-out

I'm trying to check out file which is located inside document library under sub site.

Site URL : mymainsite/subsite/subsite/My Library/test.xlsx

I'm using below PowerShell script

```
function CheckOutFile($filePath) {
    Write-Host "CheckOut file is in process"


    $response = PostRequest ("/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('/My Library/test.xlsx')/CheckOut()") (ConvertTo-Json @{ 
        __metadata = @{ type= "SPFile" }
        ServerRelativeUrl = "/My Library/test.xlsx"
    })
}
```

**Note:** If I'm trying to checkout in root site library then it is working fine when I'm referring to subsite library it showing below error.

[image]

What I'm doing wrong here :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To refer library under subsite we need to specify relative url two times like below:

```
function CheckOutFile($filePath) {
    Write-Host "CheckOut file is in process"


    $response = PostRequest ("/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('/subsite/subsite/My Library/test.xlsx')/CheckOut()") (ConvertTo-Json @{ 
        __metadata = @{ type= "SPFile" }
        ServerRelativeUrl = "/My Library/test.xlsx"
    })
}
```